# Why is erosion possible?

Tags: friction

On the one hand, I've been told that when two materials rub against each other, the harder one wins.  This is borne out by e.g. scratch tests.

On the OTHER hand, I just looked at my touchpad, and years of my soft fingertips have worn through the top layers of the hard surface.  Related are phenomena like erosion - wind and water (not even solid) wearing away stone.

These seem to conflict.  Two possible explanations come to mind.

1. Soft things can wear away hard things, it just takes vastly longer.  OR:
2. The soft things are merely carrying particles of harder substances, which over time scratch the hard thing away.  (And/or chemical effects, or freezing expansion, or some other non-friction effect.)

Which, if either, is right?  Suppose you had a perfect plate of iron, and a perfect ball of rubber (which, say, you periodically replace if it gets damaged), in a chamber devoid of even a single other particle.  Suppose you rubbed the two together for hundreds of years - would the iron plate eventually wear away?  On what sort of timescale, and due to what effects?

Bonus question - what happens as the hardness of the two materials approach a common value?  I.e., what happens if A is only *slightly* harder than B?

Comment: Somewhat related and might contain some useful information in the answers too https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19156/23615

Comment: [In other words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardness#Measuring_hardness), why is [scratch hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_hardness) (resistance to fracture from friction) different from [indentation hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_hardness) (resistance to deformation from compression)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The harder material deforms and wears less than the softer one, but wears nevertheless. However the hardness relation between materials makes a lot of difference in industrial processes.

For example: we can machine a part of cast iron using a tool of tungsten carbide. But after repeating the process with several other iron parts, the tool wears, and eventually must be replaced (or at least sharpened). Depending on the case, it can happens more than once a day. But the wear process is slow enough to allow a good precision in the final dimensions of the each part.

We could compare some geological processes to the wear of the harder tool. It is very slow compared to its action on the softer material, but it happens anyway.

Comment: That's a reasonable comparison; thanks.  Do you know of any equations relating how quickly wear occurs between two materials?  Like "wear speed is proportional to the hardness of A divided by the hardness of B, squared" or something?  Perhaps "Woodell wear resistance", mentioned in the "Scratch hardness" wiki entry, is related?

Comment: As can be seen in the formula mentioned in wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tool_wear), the tool life is roughly inversely proportional to the volume machined per time. But there are a lot of empirical coeficients, and hardness of tool and part are some of them.